# download of a Maven artifact with dependencies from Nexus using the command line

Tags: java, maven, nexus, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I'm using the command below to download a maven jar from Nexus through the command line.

```
call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=bits:update-service:1.0.3 -Ddest=Setups/Services/update-service.jar
```

But what I get is a jar without dependencies. There is already a jar with dependencies in Maven with the name `update-service-1.0.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

I tried the following:

```
call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=bits:update-service:1.0.3[:packaging[:jar]] -Ddest=Setups/Services/update-service.jar
```

But it returns the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) bits:update-service:packaging[:jar]]:1.0.3[
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=bits -DartifactId=update-service -Dversion=1.0.3[ -Dclassifier=jar]] -Dpackaging=packaging[ -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=bits -DartifactId=update-service -Dversion=1.0.3[ -Dclassifier=jar]] -Dpackaging=packaging[ -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR] 2) bits:update-service:packaging[:jar]]:1.0.3[
[ERROR]
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] temp (http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/, releases=true, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Question**: What is the correct way to download a jar with dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jar-with-dependencies` in this case is a Maven [`classifier`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates):

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number.

That is, the `1.0.4` jar and its *with-dependencies* variant differ in their Maven coordinates via the classifier.

Hence, using the `maven-dependency-plugin` and its [`get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) goal you can specify a `classifier` via the [`classifier`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#classifier) option:

> The classifier of the artifact to download. Ignored if `artifact` is used.

However, you are indeed using the [`artifact`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#artifact) option already, hence the option above will be ignored as per documentation.
If you look at the documentation of the `artifact` option though:

> A string of the form `groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging][:classifier]`.

Look at its last (optional) token, `[:classifier]`. This is exactly what you are missing.

Your `artifact` option should be as following:

```
-Dartifact=bits:update-service:1.0.4:jar:jar-with-dependencies
```

---

Note: you actually already used it incorrectly when specifying:

```
-Dartifact=bits:update-service:1.0.3[:packaging[:jar]]
```

The squared brackets `[..]` indicates optional parameters, you should not specify them in your command line invocation. Moreover the `packaging` string there specify what value to put: again, you should not specify it, but just replace it with the corresponding value (in this case `jar`).

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example to show you the way. 

I would like to download all the dependencies of spring-webmvc in version 4.2.5.RELEASE.

1) You need the pom of webmvc if not already in your local repository. If spring-webmvc is already in the local repo then skip 1).

2) You can download all the dependencies related to the pom your have just downloaded.

1. downloading of the pom

> C:\temp\spring_web_mvc>mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:get -DgroupId=org.springframework -DartifactId=spring-webmvc
>   -Dversion=4.2.5.RELEASE -Dtype=pom

2. downloading all the dependencies

> C:\temp\spring_web_mvc>mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies -f C:\repository2\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.pom -DoutputDirectory=C:\TEMP
>
> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   
> [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE
>   
> ...
>   
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   
> [INFO] Building Spring Web MVC 4.2.5.RELEASE
>   
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   
> [WARNING] The POM for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js4 is missing, no dependency information available
>   
> [INFO] 
>   
> [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies (default-cli) @ spring-webmvc ---
>   
> [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
>   
> [INFO] org.apache.tiles:tiles-request-mustache:jar:1.0.6 already exists in destination.
>   
> [INFO] com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.6.5 already exists in destination.
>   
> [INFO] org.apache.tiles:tiles-mvel:jar:3.0.5 already exists in destination.
>   
> [INFO] org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.2.2 already exists in destination.
>   
> [INFO] org.jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.23 already exists in destination.
>   
> ...
>   
> [INFO] org.apache.tiles:tiles-extras:jar:3.0.5 already exists in destination.
>   
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
>   
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   
> [INFO] Total time: 4.095 s
>   
> [INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-23T11:06:03+02:00
>   
> [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/241M
>   
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Results:

> C:\temp\spring_web_mvc>dir
>   
>  Volume in drive C has no label.
>   
>  Volume Serial Number is F400-3CE5
>   
>   
>  Directory of C:\temp\spring_web_mvc
>   
>   
> 23/06/2016  11:05              .
>   
> 23/06/2016  11:05              ..
>   
> 23/06/2016  10:24             4,467 aopalliance-1.0.jar
>   
> 23/06/2016  10:24           192,035 bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar
>   
> 23/06/2016  10:24           192,035 bcmail-jdk14-138.jar
>   ...